# Average value is not displayed automatically when values added

Tags: vba, excel

I programmatically create new Excel worksheet and add a formula calculating the average value of a certain range of values in a specific cell. However when I open this newly created worksheet, I don't automatically see the average value displayed when I type in my values on by one and I have to double click on the cell containing the average formula to display it's value, how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Is your calculation set to Manual?

Comment: I don't know, I'm very new to vba programming actually, here is the code I use to add the formulas to the cells :        `newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Cells(26, i + 2).Address()).Formula = "=MOYENNE(" + Cells(16, i + 2).Address() + ":" + Cells(25, i + 2).Address() + ")"`

Comment: Under `Formulas` tab, check in the `Calculation Options` drop down. Which one is  ticked? Alternatively, at the end of your code you can also use this `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: It is set to automatic

Comment: Then try and do what @Rory suggested in his post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `MOYENNE` to `AVERAGE` - the `.Formula` property expects US English formulas. You could also use `.FormulaLocal` if you prefer to use the function names as you would enter them.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks - obviously the coffee has done its job this morning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, what Siddharth Rout said is right
make calculation automatic by the code Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic